# Ms office document not converted to pdf when server not connected remotely

Tags: c#, asp.net

in our application, i am convert ms office document to pdf in asp.net but when i am deploy code on server then the ms office document converted to pdf only when the server is remotely connected otherwise it won't be converted Please advice?

```
Error exExcel2Pdf @ System.String[] : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 8000401a The server process could not be started because the configured identity is incorrect. Check the username and password. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000401A).
```

Comment: Do you use Word interop or some external library for the convertion?

Comment: yes i am using  interop dll

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this problem, change the identity for the server application to run under a particular user. To do this, on the Identity tab of the Application Properties dialog box, click This User. In addition, if it is feasible, you can ensure that a user is interactively logged on to the server console while the application is running.

1. In the command line put DCOMCNFG
2. Component Services -> Computers -> My Computer -> DCOM Config
3. Find "Microsoft Word 97 - 2003 Document" (If it is missing check if your Word is also 64 bit (if your Windows is))
4. Right click -> Properties
5. Go to Tab Identity and choose **other** user than "The interactive user"
6. Apply changes and try again

Source [microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/305761)

Comment: I am glad, please accept my answer so people may know that it works :)